# Missing image in CGRect

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-graphics

I used Core Graphics successfully to [draw a series of circles in a circular arc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28378461/what-is-causing-this-edge-condition-with-cgcontextaddarc) and I would like to arrange a pic file in a circular arc using Core Graphics. Following Apple's [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/HandlingImages/Images.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010156-CH13-SW8) I tried to draw the file explicitly by adding it to the app’s bundle and storing it as a UIImage so I can rotate it.

However no image appears when I use drawAtPoint

Here is my initialisation code

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        NSString *imagePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"pic"] ofType:@"png"];
        UIImage *myImageObj = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:imagePath];
        self.anImage = myImageObj;

        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    }
    return self;
}
```

And here is my method

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    [self.anImage drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(10, 10)];
}
```

Also, In the .h file I declared the property

```
@property (nonatomic,retain) UIImage* anImage;
```

Can anyone explain why no image appears ? Thanks

**EDIT:**

I’ve tried two ways to make the image appear in the frame. One is based on [Apple Developer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/HandlingImages/Images.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010156-CH13-SW10).

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect   {
NSString *imagePath     = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"pic"] ofType:@"png"];
UIImage *myImageObj     = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:imagePath];
self.anImage            = myImageObj;
[self.anImage drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(100, 100)];
[self setNeedsDisplay]; }
```

The other is based on [Technotopia](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_iPhone_Graphics_Drawing_Tutorial_using_Quartz_2D#Drawing_an_Image_into_a_Graphics_Context).

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect   {
 UIImage *myImage   = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pic.png"];
 [myImage drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(100, 100)];
 [self setNeedsDisplay]; }
```

In each case I used an image file called pic.png.

[image: pic.png]

I’ve also added this to the bundle using **Add Files** in Xcode. And in each case in order to refresh the display I’ve also added **[self setNeedsDisplay];** to **CGRect**.

The code for initialisation is now reduced.

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
if (self) {
    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor cyanColor];
}
return self; }
```

Neither approach works. The problem remains: why is this image not displayed ?

and also how do I find whether *self.anImage != nil* ?

I'd be grateful to anyone who can tell me what I've missed. Thanks.

Comment: First, make sure your init method is getting called, not initWithNib or something else. Also, why the complicated image loading, why not just `[[UIImage imageName:@"pic"] drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(10, 10)];` in the `drawRect:` method?

Comment: add [super drawRect:rect] to your drawRect, you should at least see your background getting drawn

Comment: @picciano, I know init is called because I can change background colour. Rightly or wrongly, I also believe the image needs to be loaded as a bit map so I can scale and rotate it. To do that I first need to load it this way and display it.

Comment: @CSmith, I think the background is drawn successfully during initialisation but unfortunately adding [super drawRect:rect] hasn't drawn the image.

Comment: and self.anImage != nil ?

Comment: @CSmith, seems a relevant question. How do I tell if self.anImage != nil ?

Comment: run in debugger, set a breakpoint